# The transpose of the linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

The linear map $\mathcal{A}: \mathbb R^{3n \times3n} \to \mathbb R^{3n \times n}$ is defined as following

$$\mathcal{A}(X)=
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{12} + X_{21} \\
X_{13} + X_{31} \\
X_{23} + X_{32} 
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{3n \times 3n},X_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n},i,j=1,2,3$.Is there an explicit expression for the transpose of the above linear map,any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the "transpose" of a linear map over a space of matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated, it's not clear what you mean by the "transpose" in this context. However, one frequently used notion of the "transpose" of such a map is the dual of the map relative to the Frobenius inner product.

Let $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ denote the Frobenius inner product, $\langle A,B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB^T)$. Denote
$$
X = [X_{i,j}]_{i,j=1}^3 \in \Bbb R^{3n \times 3n}, \quad Y = \pmatrix{Y_1\\Y_2\\Y_3} \in \Bbb R^{3n \times n}.
$$
We have
\begin{align}
\langle \mathcal A(X),Y \rangle &= 
\left\langle \pmatrix{X_{12} + X_{21}\\ X_{13} + X_{31}\\X_{23} + X_{32}}, \pmatrix{Y_1\\Y_2\\Y_3}\right \rangle
\\ & = 
\operatorname{tr}[(X_{12} + X_{21})Y_1^T + 
(X_{13} + X_{31})Y_2^T + (X_{23} + X_{32})Y_3^T
]
\\ & = 
\operatorname{tr}\left[ 
\pmatrix{X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{13}\\ X_{21} & X_{22} & X_{23}\\ X_{31} & X_{32} & X_{33}} \pmatrix{0 & Y_1 & Y_2\\Y_1 & 0 & Y_3\\Y_2 & Y_3 & 0}^T
\right]
 = 
\left\langle X, \pmatrix{0 & Y_1 & Y_2\\Y_1 & 0 & Y_3\\Y_2 & Y_3 & 0}
\right\rangle.
\end{align}
Thus, the "transpose" of $\mathcal A$ is the map $\mathcal A^* :\Bbb R^{3n \times n} \to \Bbb R^{3n \times 3n}$ given by
$$
\mathcal A^*(Y) = \pmatrix{0 & Y_1 & Y_2\\Y_1 & 0 & Y_3\\Y_2 & Y_3 & 0}.
$$

---

The connection to the usual "transpose" is as follows. Let the $p \times q$ matrix $E_{i,j}$ be such that its $i,j$ entry is $1$ and its other entries are $0$. Let $\mathcal B_{p,q}$ denote the basis for the space of $p \times q$ matrices consisting of the elements $E_{i,j}$ where the pairs $(i,j)$ are taken in lexicographical order. Notably, $\mathcal B_{p,q}$ is an orthonormal basis relative to the Frobenius inner product. You might also find it interesting that for a $p \times q$ matrix $X$, the coordinate vector $[X]_{\mathcal B_{p,q}}$ is the row-major vectorization of $X$.

If $M = [\mathcal A]^{\mathcal B_{3n,3n}}_{\mathcal B_{3n,n}}$, that is, $M$ is the matrix of $M$ relative to the choice of basis described above over the domain and codomain of $\mathcal A$, then $\mathcal A^*$ is the (unique) linear map for which
$$
[\mathcal A^*]^{\mathcal B_{3n,n}}_{\mathcal B_{3n,3n}} = M^T.
$$
The same statement will hold for $M = [\mathcal A]^{\mathcal B_1}_{\mathcal B_2}$ and $[\mathcal A^*]^{\mathcal B_2}_{\mathcal B_1}$ whenever the bases $\mathcal B_1$ of the domain and $\mathcal B_2$ of the codomain are orthonormal relative to the Frobenius inner product.